# Linux python django site-packages not recognized in envelope

Tags: django, python-venv, miniconda

I have tried to create envelope on my linux pop os system using miniconda. When I activate it, I can install packages using pip, but when I run my django instance it doesn't find the modules.

If I type which python is shows the miniconda path correctly. I can look in the site-packages folder and see the packages installed.

I've tried installing django-anymail and corsheaders and they are both not being found. It does find my locally installed apps.

If I use the command line and open python and then import, it does not recognize my modules installed in the virtual envelope either. I thought it was a problem with conda, so I also created an envelope using python's native method: python3 -m venv

I have the same problem with it finding pip install site-packages.

Is there a command I can run to show all available packages?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realized I had aliased my python. Now it is working.